Plotly, convert epoch timestamps (with ms) to readable datetimes?
The below code uses Python lists to create a Plotly graph.
The timestamps are Epoch milliseconds. How do I format the x-axis to readable datetime?
I tried fig.layout['xaxis_tickformat'] = '%HH-%MM-%SS' but it didn't work.
import plotly.graph_objects as go

time_series = [1716693661000, 1716693662000, 1716693663000, 1716693664000]
prices = [20, 45, 32, 19]
 
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=time_series, y=prices, yaxis='y'))

fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(rangeslider=dict(visible=True),type="linear"))
fig.layout['xaxis_tickformat'] = '%Y-%m-%d'

fig.show()


You can use fromtimestamp().strftime() from datetime:
tdt = [datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for ts in time_series]

Code


time_series = [1716693661000, 1716693662000, 1716693663000, 1716693664000]
prices = [20, 45, 32, 19]

tdt = [datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for ts in time_series]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=tdt, y=prices, yaxis='y'))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(
        rangeslider=dict(visible=True),
        type="date",
        tickformat='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    )
)

fig.show()


